# ShouldBeUnique cannot be used for Queued Event Listeners

Tags: php, laravel

How can I use `ShouldBeUnique` with *Queued Event Listeners*?

Queued Event Listeners Code:

```php
namespace App\Listeners\Test;

use App\Events\Test\RollEvent;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class CapterBEventListener implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use InteractsWithQueue;

    public $uniqueFor = 3600;

    public function handle(RollEvent $event)
    {
        echo 'RoolEventB' ,PHP_EOL;
        sleep(10);
        echo 'over--',PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function uniqid(RollEvent $event) 
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Test in `tinker`:

```sh
$ php artisan queue:restart
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) event(new App\Events\Test\RollEvent(5))
```

Execution results are not unique:

```sh
> [2022-04-30 18:29:17][VlGCdjmgniuAKbFuJ6QL7t7jLuhxzEN6] Processing: App\Listeners\Test\CapterBEventListener 
> RoolEventB
> over--
> [2022-04-30 18:29:27][VlGCdjmgniuAKbFuJ6QL7t7jLuhxzEN6] Processed: App\Listeners\Test\CapterBEventListener
> [2022-04-30 18:29:27][uh4p7EuDmVSVEf17SrbcoUdKNQ1xVKzo] Processing: App\Listeners\Test\CapterBEventListener
> RoolEventB
> over--
> [2022-04-30 18:29:37][uh4p7EuDmVSVEf17SrbcoUdKNQ1xVKzo] Processed: App\Listeners\Test\CapterBEventListener
```

Used `ShouldBeUnique` in `unique-jobs`:

```php
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class TestPodcast implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        echo 'handle start', PHP_EOL;
        sleep(10);
        echo 'handle end', PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function uniqueId() 
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Test in `tinker`:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) App\Jobs\TestPodcast::dispatch();
```

Execution result is unique:

```sh
> [2022-05-01 10:47:30][jaEFh5PeZGVeVsDRVKD3qok5LiQ7E7ub] Processing: App\Jobs\TestPodcast 
> handle start
> handle end
> [2022-05-01 10:47:30][jaEFh5PeZGVeVsDRVKD3qok5LiQ7E7ub] Processed: App\Jobs\TestPodcast
```

---

### How can I use `ShouldBeUnique` in `Queued Event Listeners`

Comment: I am not 100% sure this will work for listeners, the documentation only mentions Jobs, not Listeners

Comment: seems that your queue is running sync ? When you say that the event listeners are not unique, if you suppose that event 1 is queued, and executed, then event 2 is queued and executed then this would match your example.  Instead, don't run the worker and see how many events are queued.

Comment: You can dispatch the job inside the listener. This could be too much, but will work.